# can we make websphere portal CSA and spring MVC3 work together?

Tags: websphere-portal

I  created a portlet(jsr286) with spring mvc 3 framework. Which is working fine if the page have SSA(server side aggregation), however it stops working when working with CSA(client side aggregation).

I am using WPS 7.0 RAD 8.0.1 and spring 3.0.1.
Any suggestion will be really helpfull.
Thanks in advance!

The error that i am getting:
[2/8/11 18:09:41:750 IST] 00000037 PortletInvoke W com.ibm.wps.wsrp.producer.provider.pc.waspc.impl.PortletInvokerImpl newBlockingInteractionResponse Action execution refused due to a security violation. Action ID missing.
[2/8/11 18:09:41:781 IST] 00000037 WSRPEngine    E com.ibm.wps.wsrp.producer.impl.WSRPEngine performBlockInteraction EJPWC1109E: Normal execution of the operation failed.
                                 com.ibm.wps.wsrp.exception.WSRPException: EJPWC1109E: Normal execution of the operation failed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in WPS 7, looked at the portlet page html source, the form action attribute values is a Websphere Portal javascript in which the portlet action URL is encoded. This solution is to set the the spring form tag *htmlEscape* attribute to false to disable html escape so that the portal engine can encode the action URL correctly.

The solution is verified in Websphere Portal 7.0.0.2 with WAS Application Server 7.0.0.21 and Spring MVC 3.1.0.